# How to persist streaming data to disk in DolphinDB?

Tags: streaming, dolphindb

By default, the streaming table keeps all streaming data in memory.How can I persist streaming data  to disk in DolphinDB? For example, I have a stream table like following:

```
n=20000000
colNames = `time`sym`qty`price
colTypes = [TIME,SYMBOL,INT,DOUBLE]
t=streamTable(n:0, colNames, colTypes)
share t as trades_stream
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call enableTablePersistence or enableTableShareAndPersistence to  persist data to disk.Examples are as follows:

```
n=20000000
colNames = `time`sym`qty`price
colTypes = [TIME,SYMBOL,INT,DOUBLE]
t=streamTable(n:0, colNames, colTypes)
enableTableShareAndPersistence(t,`trades_stream,true,true,1200000)
```